# Spark NotSerializableException

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

In my Spark code, I am attempting to create an IndexedRowMatrix from a csv file. However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
```

Here is my code:

```
sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "App",
              "/srv/spark", new String[]{"target/App.jar"});

JavaRDD<String> csv = sc.textFile("data/matrix.csv").cache();


JavaRDD<IndexedRow> entries = csv.zipWithIndex().map(
              new  Function<scala.Tuple2<String, Long>, IndexedRow>() {
                /**
                 * 
                **/ 
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 4795273163954440089L;

                @Override
                public IndexedRow call(Tuple2<String, Long> tuple)
                        throws Exception {
                    String line = tuple._1;
                    long index = tuple._2;
                    String[] strings = line.split(",");
                    double[] doubles = new double[strings.length];
                     for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                         doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
                     }
                     Vector v = new DenseVector(doubles);
                     return new IndexedRow(index, v);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Questions asking for debug help should (1) show an *entire* self-contained program that demonstrates the problem, (2) show the *entire* stack trace, and (3) indicate the line where the exception happens.

Comment: That said, I'm betting that `sc` is a member variable of the containing class. Don't do that, just make it a local variable *like all of the examples in the Spark documentation*.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
It drove me around the twist.
It is a Java restriction for anonymous instances and Serializability.
My solution was to declare the anonymous instance of the Function as a named static class that implements Serializable and to instantiate it.
I basically declared a functions library that was an outer class that included static inner class definitions of the functions I wanted to use.

Of course, if you write it in Scala, it will be one file most probably with much neater code, but that is not going to help you in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

When you have issues with serialization, it's always good to add the following argument : `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` this way you can see where it fails more precisely.

Now, here's what might be happening in your code. A `JavaSparkContext` is indeed not serializable (for a bunch of reasons that you could find on the web). In your code you're not serializing it directly but you do hold a reference to it because your `Function` is not static and hence it holds a reference to the enclosing class. So what basically happens when you send the map is that it will try to serialize also the enclosing class that contains the `JavaSparkContext` which is not serializable, this is where your exception should come from. You could try rewritting this function either statically, or write your function as a non-nested class or make the `JavaSparkContext` local so that it is not serialized.

If possible I rather advice that you take the latest option for the simple reason that it is best practice to create this `JavaSparkContext` locally because otherwise you'll have hundreds of non-serializable issues due to every reference (sometimes tricky to find) you might hold to your class. You could do this for instance by instanciating your `JavaSparkContext` inside your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();

   // do whatever you need to do, if you need sc inside other classes,
   // store this sc into a static class, say Registry.set(sc) and Registry.getJSC()

   JavaRDD<String> csv = sc.textFile("data/matrix.csv").cache();
   JavaRDD<IndexedRow> entries = csv.zipWithIndex().map(
          new  Function<scala.Tuple2<String, Long>, IndexedRow>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4795273163954440089L; // won't be serialized

            @Override
            public IndexedRow call(Tuple2<String, Long> tuple)
                    throws Exception {
                String line = tuple._1;
                long index = tuple._2;
                String[] strings = line.split(",");
                double[] doubles = new double[strings.length];
                 for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                     doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
                 }
                 Vector v = new DenseVector(doubles);
                 return new IndexedRow(index, v);
            }
        });
}
```

Note also that static fields are not associated to an instance but to the class so I think your `serialVersionUID` is not serialized either (in case it becomes a problem for you at some point).

Answer (score 2):

Something smells fishy and if you showed us more code maybe we could give a better answer.

Anyway, you could try to create a public class in a separate file that represents your mapper function:

```
public class Mapper implements Function<Tuple2<String,Long>, IndexedRow> {

  @Override
  public IndexedRow call(Tuple2<String, Long> tuple) throws Exception {
    String line = tuple._1();
    long index = tuple._2();
    String[] strings = line.split(",");
    double[] doubles = new double[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
      doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
    }
    Vector v = new DenseVector(doubles);
    return new IndexedRow(index, v);
  }
}
```

And then use it to map your JavaRDD:

```
JavaRDD<String> csv = jsc.textFile("data/matrix.csv").cache();
JavaRDD<IndexedRow> entries = csv.zipWithIndex().map(new Mapper());
```

This way, for that map() call, Spark only needs to serialize the Mapper class which doesn't have any non-serializable properties in it.

Nevertheless, the job could fail for other reasons that we can't know because we can't see the all the code involved.

Answer (score 1):

Create A separate Class for your mapper and implements Srielizable , sometimes inner  Classes cause compiling issue in the  spark environment..

Answer (score 0):

Any code that's written in driver and is being used in RDD transformations needs to be serialized. If you are getting issues about serialisation pleass follow the below design principals:

1. Write all code that uses non-serializable objects inside the transformations (map).
2. Make use of `forEachPartition` in Spark to perform an action per partition.
   Any code that is shared by RDD transformations must always be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

In general the Rdd objects will be serialized by spark when the tasks are submitted to different executors. But you should use closure so that this error can be avoided.

You can use Rdd.mapPartition() for processing each partitions and place your code inside that. In this way spark itself will take care of serialising and deserialising the map objects.